# NHibernate Queryable not allowing string comparison

Tags: c#, nhibernate, iqueryable

I have the following code

```
var results =
                repository.GetItemsAsQuery<User>().Where(
                    user => user.EmailAddress.Equals(emailAddress, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

            return results.Any();
```

Repository is just my wrapper around the NHibernate session and that method has the following signature

```
public IQueryable<T> GetItemsAsQuery<T>()
        {
            try
            {
                CheckHasErrored();

                return _connection.Session.Query<T>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HasErrored = true;
                throw new DataRepositoryException(string.Format("Error getting collection of items of type '{0}'", typeof(T).Name), "DataRepository.GetItems<>", ex);        
            }
        }
```

When I run the first method, I get the error NotSupportException - Boolean Equals(System.String, System.StringComparison) with source NHibernate.

Which seems to imply the error is coming from the LINQ lambda expression that I am trying to filter the NHibernate query on

```
user.EmailAddress.Equals(emailAddress, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Am I using NHibernate Queryable wrong? The equivalent SQL I want it to generate is

```
select * from User where emailAddress = @emailAddress
```

So I only get one row returned across the data network.

Comment: I'm not sure what database you are using. By default, text comparisons in SQL Server are not case sensitive, in that case, you can use the standard `==` or `.Equals(string)`.

Answer (score 4):

I see two big problems with your question/what you want:

- Your desired SQL query is incompatible with your string comparison method. Your string comparison method would return true when comparing "StRiNg" and "string", since it ignores the strings' case, while your SQL query would return false when comparing these strings. If you want to ignore case when comparing, you should change your query to:

repository.GetItemsAsQuery().Where(
                user => user.EmailAddress.ToLower() == emailAddress.ToLower());

And if I'm not mistaken this is already possible with NHibernate.

- Your next big problem is trying to make a culture aware comparison in your SQL query. This is not yet possible with NHibernate. If you want culture aware string comparison SQL queries you will have to write these queries in plain SQL. For a simple equality comparison, however, you probably won't have a problem: just use the `==` operator for string comparison and you will do just fine.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

`String.Compare` is now supported in `NHibernate`.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is not yet 100% compatible with Nhibernate. Try using `String.Compare(string a, string b)` instead.

Comment: Still getting System.NotSupportedException : Int32 Compare(System.String, System.String)